# Save Pandas data frame with ndarray in cells

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, word2vec

I need to save a pandas data frame with two columns of word embeddings (Word2Vec) which are stored as ndarrays of dim (1300, 300), a string and another array with the one hot representation of that string.

```
TYPE    content   title one_hot_label
------------------------------------------------------------
happy   [[-0.25195312, 0.13085938, 0.05053711, -0.0417... [[0.12792969, -0.055908203, 0.011230469, 0.283... [0, 1, 0]
sad     [[-0.25195312, 0.13085938, 0.05053711, -0.0417... [[0.12792969, -0.055908203, 0.011230469, 0.283... [0, 1, 0]
happy   [[-0.25195312, 0.13085938, 0.05053711, -0.0417... [[0.12792969,-0.055908203, 0.011230469, 0.283...  [0, 1, 0]
sad     [[-0.25195312, 0.13085938, 0.05053711, -0.0417... [[0.12792969, -0.055908203, 0.011230469, 0.283... [0, 1, 0]
...
...
...
```

I need to persist it in my drive. I tried serializing it (`df.to_picke`) and worked well as long as the number of entries is low. CSV (`df.to_csv`) adds ellipsis to the Numpy array columns and `to_hdf` gives me overflow error.

Is there any way to save large datasets with this structure?

**EDIT**

Calling `df.memory_usage(deep=True)` gives me:

`Index                 23840
type                 244425
content          5447697600
title              62976000
one_hot_label        309920
dtype: int64`

**EDIT 2**

Could you give me another structure for creating this dataset of embeddings?

Thanks

Comment: how about [savetxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html)

Comment: Can't answer your question, but does your problem allow avoiding the `DataFrame` in the first place? Maybe just keep your vectors inside a higher dimensional numpy array...

Comment: Already tried that, but had problems related to not being 1D arrays  @anky_91(TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars)

Comment: This is an awkward data frame.  'csv' is normally rows and columns of strings and numbers.  It doesn't save arrays directly.  Instead it saves their `str(..)` representation, hence the ellipsis and [].  When you load such a csv you get strings in those cells, not array.  I'd suggest considering a different data structure.

Comment: Why aren't you saving those arrays directly?  Possibly with `np.savez` using 'happy' as a name?

Comment: @hpaulj Trying to save each column of the DataFrame gives `RuntimeError: File size unexpectedly exceeded ZIP64 limit`. I've edited the description with the size of each column of the dataframe un bytes.
Saving each row as a file is impossible. I'm working with hundreds of thousands of rows...

Comment: I'd give Apache Arrow/Parquet a try.

Comment: `ArrowInvalid: ('Can only convert 1-dimensional array values'` @aventurin

Answer (score -1):

You may decrease your data size by using this function.

```
def reduce_mem_usage(self, df, verbose=True):
    numerics = ['int16', 'int32', 'int64', 'float16', 'float32', 'float64']
    start_mem = df.memory_usage().sum() / 1024**2
    for col in df.columns:
        col_type = df[col].dtypes
        if col_type in numerics:
            c_min = df[col].min()
            c_max = df[col].max()
            if str(col_type)[: 3] == 'int':
                if c_min > np.iinfo(np.int8).min and c_max < np.iinfo(np.int8).max:
                    df.loc[:, col] = df[col].astype(np.int8)
                elif c_min > np.iinfo(np.int16).min and c_max < np.iinfo(np.int16).max:
                    df.loc[:, col] = df[col].astype(np.int16)
                elif c_min > np.iinfo(np.int32).min and c_max < np.iinfo(np.int32).max:
                    df.loc[:, col] = df[col].astype(np.int32)
                elif c_min > np.iinfo(np.int64).min and c_max < np.iinfo(np.int64).max:
                    df.loc[:, col] = df[col].astype(np.int64)
            else:
                if c_min > np.finfo(np.float16).min and c_max < np.finfo(np.float16).max:
                    df.loc[:, col] = df[col].astype(np.float16)
                elif c_min > np.finfo(np.float32).min and c_max < np.finfo(np.float32).max:
                    df.loc[:, col] = df[col].astype(np.float32)
                else:
                    df.loc[:, col] = df[col].astype(np.float64)
    end_mem = df.memory_usage().sum() / 1024**2
    if verbose:
        print('Mem. usage decreased to {:5.2f} Mb ({:.1f}% reduction)'.format(end_mem, 100 * (start_mem - end_mem) / start_mem))
    return df
```